# Return to main screen of the app if clicking the back button will close the entire application

Tags: flutter

I set up deep linking in my application. When the application is not opened (not even in the background) I open the app's URL and it takes me to the correct page. But clicking the back button closes the entire app because there is no previous screen that it can pop to.

I want to make it go to whatever screen I was in before the current one, or go to the main screen if there is no previous screen.

This is how I'm setting up the deep linking:

```
Future<void> _initApp() async {

    await _initUriHandler();
    await _incomingLinkHandler();
}

  Future<void> _initUriHandler() async {
    if (_initialUriLinkHandled) {
      return;
    }
    _initialUriLinkHandled = true;
    var navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    try {
      final initialUrl = await getInitialLink();
      if (initialUrl != null) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(initialUrl);
        var goToScreen = getScreen(uri);
        if (goToScreen == null) {
          return;
        }
        navigator.pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => goToScreen));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      navigator.pushReplacementNamed(AppRoutes.main);
    }
  }

  _incomingLinkHandler() {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return;
    }

    var navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    _streamSubscription = uriLinkStream.listen((Uri? uri) {
      var goToScreen = getScreen(uri);
      if (goToScreen == null) {
        return;
      }
      navigator
          .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => goToScreen));
    }, onError: (err) => navigator.pushReplacementNamed(AppRoutes.main));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `WillPopScope` widget to handle back button presses.

The screen where you navigate to, for ex: `GoToScreen` could be made something like this:

In GoToScreen build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return WillPopScope(
       onWillPop: (){
           if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
               Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Has some routes below this route. We can safely pop this route.
           } else {
               Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement("/"); //Pushing the home route if no routes are available before this route.
           }
           return true;
       },
       child: YourRootWidgetPreviously(),
   );
}
```